# How to use private functions from pytorch optimizer

Tags: python, pytorch, private

I'm trying to use private functions that pytorch code imports from optimizer, such as _use_grad_for_differentiable. Importing them would be preferred but if that doesn't work I was thinking of finding the code and copying it. So far I can't do either. Any ideas?